# Div not resizing on page load/refresh

Tags: jquery, resize

I have a div I'm trying to resize with jQuery based on the window size. My code for resizing with changes of window size works great, but for some reason it doesn't work on load. I wrote the original code a few weeks back, so it's not exactly fresh in my mind, but I did fix the issue. For some reason it's not working now. I did change a few things, but nothing having to do with the script itself. Not sure why it isn't working now. The solution I came up with before seemed a bit redundant to me, as it was functions to resize the element, then functions to resize the elements on page re-size. I'm fairly new at this, so it's probably something very fundamental, but I can't figure it out. I tried putting the first part in a $(window).load() function, but all that did was make the resize on window resize part not work.

Anyhow, here's the code:

```
var width = $(window).width();
function resizeBig() {
    $("#topbarMainBlockContainer").css("width", "calc(100% - 420px)");
}
function resizeSmall() {
    $("#topbarMainBlockContainer").css("width", "100%");
}
if (width < 700) {
    resizeSmall();
} else {
resizeBig();
}
$(window).resize(function () {
    width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 700) {
        resizeSmall();
    } else {
        resizeBig();
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with enclosing you code in document ready?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// code goes here
});
```

Or load your script before the body closing tag.

The reason is the interpreter might not find the element with id #topbarMainBlockContainer when the code is executed as the page is still not loaded completely.

Comment: That did it! Thanks Sergio!

Comment: Awesome I'm glad it helped. I'm still young in this community so marking my answer as correct would help me heaps ;)